# Css3 select an element using 2 classes

Tags: css, styles, zurb-foundation, stylesheet

I tried to select an element using 2 classes, but it didn't work for some reason!.

I'm trying to select the large-3, because I want to change the width.

Anyway the css code I wrote:

```
.plans.large-3  {
    width: 30% !important;
}
```

The whole code!

```
 <section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns plans">
                <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns plans_title">
                    <h5>Price</h5>
                    <h2>Your Plan</h2>
                    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-4 columns plans_price">
                    <h5>Test</h5>
                    <h5>5 Days</h5>
                    <h1>Free</h1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```css
.plans > .large-3 {
  width: 30% !important;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns plans">
      <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns plans_title">
        <h5>Price</h5>
        <h2>Your Plan</h2>
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-4 columns plans_price">
        <h5>Test</h5>
        <h5>5 Days</h5>
        <h1>Free</h1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

It will select the elements with class `large-3` that are direct descendants of elements with class `.plans`. See [child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) on MDN for more info.

Comment: Ohhh nice it works, can you explain how dose it work. I can't understand the usage of ">" sign

Answer (score 1):

If you want the css to effect both plans and large-3 then a comma separating the 2 would work.

```css
.plans .large-3 {
  width: 30% !important;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns plans">
      <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns plans_title">
        <h5>Price</h5>
        <h2>Your Plan</h2>
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-4 columns plans_price">
        <h5>Test</h5>
        <h5>5 Days</h5>
        <h1>Free</h1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      <!-- ****************** not in plans class ******************** -->
       <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-4 columns plans_price">
        <h5>Test</h5>
        <h5>5 Days</h5>
        <h1>Free</h1
      </div>
     <!-- ****************** not in plans class ******************** -->
      
</section>
```

Comment: I want  large-3 to be effected only,because I'm using it in many places so I don't want to effect the whole site.

Comment: ok, just add a space between the 2 classes. The snippet above demonstrates.